# Facebook Messenger Chat Plugin with NextJS

Tags: next.js, facebook-messenger-bot

I'am trying to add Facebook messenger chatbot to my NextJs app. During the setup Facebook asking me to add this code snippet to my website.

```html
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
      xfbml: true,
      version: "v9.0",
    });
  };

  (function (d, s, id) {
    var js,
      fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  })(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
</script>

<!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat" attribution="setup_tool" page_id="..."></div>
```

Of course this code does not work with NextJs. Is there any Idea how can I integrate with it.

Comment: In case anyone else needs this, here's what I done to add FB Messenger code to my NextJS app - As mentioned before, you need to drop the plugin code into _document.js: https://gist.github.com/albertpak/dff14385102fe76513b9d7bfc9b03412

Answer (score 1):

your can input code inside tag  file _document.js
or use Google Tag Manger

Comment: Can you provide code snippet for the usage in _document.js ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/albertpak/dff14385102fe76513b9d7bfc9b03412